# Sequence that converges to the limit inferior of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$. The limit inferior of $f$ at $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x) = \lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0}\left(\inf\{f(x)\mid x \in (x_0 + \varepsilon B_n)\setminus\{x_0\}\}\right)
\end{equation}
where $B_n$ is the closed unit ball. I am trying to prove or disprove the following conjecture:

> There exists a sequence $\{x_k\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $x_k \to x_0$ and $f(x_k) \to \liminf_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ as $k \to \infty$.

My first trial was as follows:

> Define $U_k = (x_0 + \varepsilon_k B_n)\setminus\{x_0\}$ and $m_k = \inf\{f(x)\mid x \in U_k\}$ with $\varepsilon_1 > \varepsilon_2 > \cdots$ and $\varepsilon_k \to 0$. Then, $m_1 \le m_2 \le \cdots$ and $m_k \to \liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x)$. If we pick a point $x_k$ from a set $V_k = \{x\in U_k\mid m_k \le f(x) \le m_{k+1}\}$, then $x_k \to x_0$ and $f(x_k) \to \liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x)$.

However, if $\liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x) = \inf\{f(x)\mid x \in U_1\}$ and $\liminf_{x\to x_0}f(x) \notin f(U_1)$, then $V_k = \emptyset$ and the proof does not work. Would you give me any hint or reference?

===================================================================
Edit:

I have corrected the proof thanks to Martin Argerami's answer.

> Define $U(\varepsilon) = (x_0 + \varepsilon B_n)\setminus\{x_0\}$ and $m(\varepsilon) = \inf\{f(x)\mid x \in U(\varepsilon)\}$. Then, $m(\varepsilon) \to m_0 = \liminf_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$.
>
> 1) If there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $m(\varepsilon) = +\infty$, then $f(x) = +\infty$ for every $x \in U(\varepsilon)$, so $f(x_k) \to m_0 = +\infty$ for every sequence $\{x_k\}$ that converges to $x_0$.
>
> Suppose $m(\varepsilon) < +\infty$ for all $\varepsilon >0$.
>
> 2) If there exists $\varepsilon_1 >0$ such that $m(\varepsilon) = -\infty$ for every $0 < \varepsilon \le \varepsilon_1$, then let $\varepsilon_1 > \varepsilon_2 > \cdots$ such that $\varepsilon_k \to 0$.
>
> 2-1) If $-\infty \in f(U(\varepsilon_k))$, let $x_k \in U(\varepsilon_k)$ such that $f(x_k) = -\infty$.
>
> 2-2) If $-\infty \notin f(U(\varepsilon_k))$, let $x_k \in U(\varepsilon_k)$ such that $f(x_k) < -k$; such $x_k$ exists by the definition of the infimum.
>
> Then $x_k \to x_0$ and $f(x_k) \to m_0 = -\infty$ as $k \to \infty$ because $f(x_k) < -k$.
>
> 3) If there exists $\varepsilon_1 >0$ such that $-\infty < m(\varepsilon_1) < +\infty$, then $-\infty < m(\varepsilon) < +\infty$ for every $0 <\varepsilon \le \varepsilon_1$. Let $\varepsilon_1 > \varepsilon_2 > \cdots$ such that $\varepsilon_k \to 0$. By the definition of the infimum, there exists $x_k \in U(\varepsilon_k)$ with $|f(x_k) - m(\varepsilon_k)| < 1/k$. Then $x_k \to x_0$ and
>   \begin{equation}
> \lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_k) = \lim_{k\to\infty}m(\varepsilon_k) = m_0.
> \end{equation}

Comment: In the $-\infty$ argument, you cannot say that $f(x_k)=-\infty$; you can say that $f(x_k)$ is very negative, but it doesn't have to be infinite.

Comment: @Martin Argerami Would you explain a little bit more why $f(x_k) = -\infty$ is not possible when $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$? I guess that if both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ are in the range of $f$, then $\infty - \infty$ could happen but I am not sure if it is the reason.

Comment: It is not that it is not possible; it is not certain. For instance consider $f(t)=1/t$ and $f(0)=0$. With the definition you gave, $\liminf_{t\to0} f(t)=-\infty$, but there is no $t$ with $f(t)=-\infty$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami It will be handled by the case 2-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of inf, for each $k $ there exists $x_k\in U_k $ with $|m_k-f (x_k)|<1/k $. Then 
$$
\liminf_{x\to x_0}f (x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}m_k=\lim_{k\to\infty}f (x_k).
$$

You need to deal with the $\pm\infty $ case on its own, but the spirit is the same.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have corrected the proof by your answer.